# Как написать скрипт для переименования файлов с сохранением расширения?

Tags: bat

Всем привет. Прошу помочь с написанием скрипта BAT, т.к. сам я в нем полный ноль.
Задача. Имеется несколько файлов:

setup.exe
setup-1.bin
setup-2.bin

Нужно их все переименовать, чтобы получилось

setup_ver1.0.exe
setup-1_ver1.0.bin
setup-2_ver1.0.bin

Короче говоря, в конце имени файла, перед расширением дописать _ver1.0. Как это можно сделать?
Пробовал кучу вариантов, типа
ren "setup*" "setup*_ver-1.0.*"

И в цикле, ничего не помогало. Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: А не проще для таких целей использовать, например, python

Comment: Там есть модуль, который позволяет получить все файлы одного расширения
https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html
См. or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif)